# Show div if option value is selected keeps refreshing page?

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I am trying to hide/show a div based on if a checkbox value is selected or not. Found some code, did some customizations but now the page keeps refreshing every time. Can someone help me out?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){                  
       if($(this).val() == '0'){
            $("#cp_doel_lening").attr('checked', false); 
            $("#cp_doel_lening2").attr('checked', false); 
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").hide();
       }
       if($(this).val() == '7'){
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").show();
       }
       if($(this).val() == '8'){
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").show();
       }
       if($(this).val() == '9'){
            $("#cp_doel_lening").attr('checked', false); 
            $("#cp_doel_lening2").attr('checked', false);
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").hide();
       }
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

My css code:

```
div.custom_doel { 
    display: none;
}
```

Then my html code:

```
<form><select name='scat' id='scat' class='postform' >
    <option value='0' selected='selected'>Alle rubrieken</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="9">Ervaringen</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="7">Man</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="8">Vrouw</option>
</select><input type="submit" ></form>

<div class="custom_doel" id="box">
            <strong>Doel lening</strong>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="cp_doel_lening[]" value="Particulier" id="cp_doel_lening" <?php 
    if (in_array('Particulier', $_GET['cp_doel_lening']) ) {
        echo 'checked';
    }
     ?> />Particulier</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="cp_doel_lening[]" value="Zakelijk" id="cp_doel_lening2" <?php 
    if (in_array('Zakelijk', $_GET['cp_doel_lening']) ) {
        echo 'checked';
    }
     ?> />Zakelijk</label></li>
</div>
```

Why keeps my page refreshing continuously? I noticed that if i deleted the `.change()` from my javascript code then it would'nt happen anymore but then the div will be hided as well on a form search (on the search results page), which is logical (i guess) because the css code has a display:none;).
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a *dirty* fix which goes as follows; I easily checked if the form is submitted and if so the display is set to 'block'.
On the place of `<div class="custom_doel" id="box">` I changed it to:

```
<?php
            if (in_array('Zakelijk', $_GET['cp_doel_lening']) || in_array('Particulier', $_GET['cp_doel_lening']) ) { ?>
            <div class="custom_doel" id="box" style="display:block;">
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="custom_doel" id="box">
            <?php } ?>
```

Furthermore the .change(); is deleted from the jquery, which resulted in this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){                  
       if($(this).val() == '0'){
            $("#cp_doel_lening").attr('checked', false); 
            $("#cp_doel_lening2").attr('checked', false); 
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").hide();
       }
       if($(this).val() == '7'){
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").show();
       }
       if($(this).val() == '8'){
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").show();
       }
       if($(this).val() == '9'){
            $("#cp_doel_lening").attr('checked', false); 
            $("#cp_doel_lening2").attr('checked', false);
            $("#box").hide();
            $(".custom_doel").hide();
       }
    })
});
</script>
```